# New comer to Android Development

Tags: android

I am newcomer to android development. I was using android mobile for more than 2 years i am very impressed with the way that Apps work and Look and also its very helpful.

I am planning to develop a App for Android have an Idea to develop.

Can you please provide the best Guidance to start with the development ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning to program

Comment: If you search online (Google/Amazon/Etc) you can find great books and tutorials. Post here only when, after reading there tutorials, you have a problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download the [SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from google and fire up your IDE.

Then I would recommend going to the [Android Development Getting Started](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and the [Build your First App](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p) tutorials from Google to get a start on developing apps for Android.